# Liferay Service Builder : how to use hibernate session factory for relation

Tags: liferay, liferay-service-builder

In my project i have multiple liferay plugin portlets.  I have used single plugin in portlet having service builder. All other plugin portlets are using same service builder portlet.
Ex:
Portlet1, Poertlet2, Portlet3 and ServiceBuilder portlet.  Portlet1, Poertlet2, Portlet3 are using same ServiceBuilder portlet.

This service builder is connected to external database. And i am inserting/fetching data from this external database. There are one to many and many to one relationship structure in database. I want to use hibernate relationship model for these relationship and run complex queries to fetch data. So i want to use hibernate session factory in my service builder.

Please give your valuable advice or code so that i can do this as per the requirement.

Please note: 
1. I have read about liferay relationship in tables. But this has not work as per my requirement. 
2. Most of tables are managed by other application. I am using their data only.

Answer (score 0):

Service builder does not work this way and if you want the relation you should not use it.

The idea behind service builder is to have an easy DB access layer - entity at a time and the relations are resolved in the business logic.

If you want that the relations are handled by the persistence layer you need to use plain hibernate.

Comment: Yes that is my concern. How can i use hibernate like this. Either i have to use hibernate session factory in my service builder impl or use pure hibernate application. So which approach i should have to use so that my code is accessible to all plugin portlets.

Comment: you have 2 options: use service builder and use it how it was intended to be used or use your own persistence layer as you wish. The end result needs to be a set of services that are registered into the OSGi register (Class annotated @Componet) that will provide the logic to the presentation layer.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to fo with the flow and used SB even of its more work. It has all the Spring, OSGi, hibernated combination sorted out. If you go your own path google for Hibernate, OSGi and Declarative services. You probably end up [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/osgi/OSGi.html) and [here](http://aries.apache.org/) and you need to find out how to put it together. Side note: Liferay using Declarative services. You can use blueprint but it would be best to keep it in separate bandle.

Comment: A bit out of the box option is to create a SpringBoot/standard web app that will provide a REST API over your database and consume that in the OSGi bundle.

Comment: Thanks @Miroslav, I have created rest api with hibernate for this. But i was finding if it is possible in liferay too.